# Optimizing Stop Loss Percentage for a Specific Model Based on Stock Price to Maximize Expected Value

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, bayesian-optimization, bayesian-statistics

I'm fine-tuning a specific trading model, and a crucial parameter I'm keen on optimizing is the stop loss percentage. The primary objective is to maximize the Expected Value (EV), formulated as:

$$EV = \text{probability of winning} \times \text{average gain %} - \text{probability of loss} \times \text{average loss %}$$

My dataset comprises a comprehensive list of trading signals from this model spanning a long period, which I utilize to compute the EV.

A unique challenge I've encountered is the dynamic nature of the optimal stop loss percentage, which appears to vary depending on the current stock price. A few observations include:

1. At a stock price of 1 dollar, the optimal stop loss might be 5%.
2. At 5 dollars, it might be 10%.
3. And at 5.5 dollars, it could be 7%.

I've been exploring Bayesian Optimization as a potential solution, yet I'm uncertain about its efficacy given the inherent dynamic nature of the optimal parameter. Another consideration has been using a neural network to predict the optimal stop loss percentage in relation to the stock price.

Given the constraints of my specific model and the aim to optimize dynamically based on stock price, are there methods or frameworks tailored for such dynamic parameter optimization, especially when the primary goal is maximizing EV?

**EDIT**

A signal could be as simple as `{"symbol": "ABIX", "date": "2005-08-04", "signal": "SELL", "reason": "Overextended gap-down detected."}`

**EDIT**

$$EV = EV(\text{parameter_1}, \text{parameter_2}, \text{stop_loss_%}, \dots)$$

and

there exits a function $f$ such that $f(\text{entry_price}) = \text{stop_loss_%}$. Be aware that the $\text{stop_loss_%}$ correspond to $\text{stop_loss_price} = \text{entry_price} * (1 + \text{stop_loss_%})$

Comment: Please, consider sharing data if not at least column label of it. It would help us to understand better. Regarding output varying by initial condition, stock price, I have seen Support Vector Machine with Kernel Trick used, https://towardsdatascience.com/the-kernel-trick-c98cdbcaeb3f.

Comment: @CloudCho I modified the question. Maybe you could build a full answer I could understand your point

Comment: Thanks for the sample data, but I don't see "current stock price" in your data. Does your model have to guess that as well? What is the output of your model between stop loss percentage and Expected Value?

Comment: @CloudCho From there, I just pull the minute OLHC data, calculate the entry point, exit point and stop loss point and compute the expected value for the model.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, so the "stock price" isn't one of input variables in you model?

Comment: @CloudCho I modified the question so you can understand a bit better.